# Что лучше AMD Ryzen 5 1600 или Intel Core i5 7400

Tags: железо, cpu, intel, amd

Возник вопрос по смене рабочего компьютера, а так как я не больно то слежу за развитием железа, то принять решение в выборе компонентов довольно сложно, плюс еще бюджет ограничен **40к** на системный блок. Сейчас, чтобы влезть в бюджет остановился на двух вариантах процессоров **AMD Ryzen 5 1600** или **Intel Core i5 7400**. Но никак не могу найти нормальных сравнений, все сравнения в основном в играх, но мне не для игр нужно. Мне нужно, чтобы быстро кодировал зипы, компилил исходники и тд. и чтобы антивирус не тормозил работу.
В работе использую:
Visual Studio,
Web Storm,
PHP Storm,
Android Studio,
Oracle VirtualBox,
Python,
NodeJS,
MongoDB,
MySQL,
Oracle,
PostgreSQL,
Win 10,
(Разные IDE для микроконтроллеров)

Comment: Чтобы быстро компилил - нужен SSD и много оперативки. А из этих двух - выбирайте то что понравится.

Comment: Для специалиста Ryzen 5 1600 будет более оптимальным выбором т.к. имеет больше ядер и за счет этого лучше покажет себя во время одновременной работы большого кол-ва приложений. 
Как альтернативу Ryzen 5 я бы посоветовал i5-8400, т.к. в Coffe Lake у i5 было увеличено кол-во ядер.

Comment: Где-то более года назад, тоже стоял перед таким же выбором и выбрал Intel i7, поставил SSD и 16Гиг оперативки, за все время ни разу не пожалел о выборе. В принципе равные варианты, но мое мнение Intel предпочтительнее выглядит(ну конечно там на поколения смотреть надо еще).

Comment: http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i5-7400-vs-AMD-Ryzen-5-1600/3886vs3919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваши требования "чтобы не тормозил при компиляции" и ваш вопрос "какой из этих двух процессоров выбрать" соотносятся достаточно слабо.

Реально, замена винта на SSD даёт существенный прирост в скорости компиляции, а процессор вносит намного меньший вклад.

Из этих двух процессоров можете выбирать любой, я бы например по любви к бренду выбрал бы Intel, хотя я согласен, что если смотреть умом, а не сердцем – то у AMD'шного параметры лучше (количество голов/потоков)